# gtk+ win32 threads

Tags: c, winapi, gtk, pthreads

From http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/unstable/gdk-Threads.html

> With the Win32 backend, GDK calls should not be attempted from
>   multiple threads at all.

But how to avoid freezing of an interface?

For example, I have a callback for a button that gets virtual machine names from host and add it row by row to Tree List View. I create pthread that do it and adds rows.

**Sometimes** List View became garbaged (some cells became blank), after it all application behave the same (all dialogs etc)

As in WIN32 multi-threading is impossible, what can I do to simulate it or avoid such issues?

Comment: win32 thread is absolutely possible, you can't simply update the UI from multiple thread, that is completely a different thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do a thread as you are doing and from there add whatever you want to pass to the GUI to a global container. Then call `g_idle_add()` to schedule a function that will read this container and update the GUI;  the idle callback will be called from the GUI thread.

Two things to be aware of:

1. Call `g_thread_init()` or `gdk_thread_init()` in the initialization of your program to make glib thread-safe.
2. Protect the global container with a mutex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just started working with threads. Now I understand what I've read about g_idle_add.

Answer (score 1):

Just for replying to this question:

> ```
> But how to avoid freezing of an interface?
> ```

Indipendently from the toolkit you are using for UI, this is achieved by doing computation in a different thread from the UI one. Then update the UI by using messages to reflect the changes in the data. Never update the UI from a thread different from the one hwo created the window.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. The problem is I need to pass to row a complex data. And I just started to write my first multi-thread application. I hope I understand it all right it it will work